# Javascript Confirm not working

Tags: php, javascript, confirm

```
echo "<td><a onclick=\"confirm('Are you sure you want to permanently delete this post?');\" href='posts.php?id=".$res['id']."'>view</a></td>";
```

Generated with PHP, the confirm isn't popping up.. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for lookin.

Comment: It will help if you provide some console logs.... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to permanently delete this post?');"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
echo "<td><a onclick='return confirm('Are you sure you want to permanently delete this post?');' href='posts.php?id=".$res['id']."'>view</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

use instead:

```
echo "<td><a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to permanently delete this post?');" href="posts.php?id=".$res['id']."'>view</a></td>";
```

`confirm` return `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

Add return false or true to avoid further execution

```
    if(Confirm())
           return true;
        else
          return false;
```

Comment: Would be better to directly return the result of Confirm().